# Mantain order of dataframe for a stacked barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Using the following dataframe and ggplot...

```
sample ="BC04"
df<- data.frame(Name=c("Pseudomonas veronii", "Pseudomonas stutzeri", "Janthinobacterium lividum", "Pseudomonas viridiflava"),
                 Abundance=c(7.17, 4.72, 3.44, 3.33))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=sample, y=Abundance, fill=Name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

... creates the following graph

[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L24q.jpg)

Altough the "geom_bar(stat="identity")" is set to "identity", it still ignores the order in the dataframe. I would like to get a stack order based on the Abundance percentage (**Highest percentage at the top with ascending order**)

Comment: There should be a column named `BC04` in the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier, strings passed to `ggplot`, are evaluated with `aes_string` (which is now deprecated).  Now, we convert the string to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x= !! rlang::sym(sample), y=Abundance, fill=Name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

---

Or another option is `.data`

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x= .data[[sample]]), y=Abundance, fill=Name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

#### Update

By checking the plot, it may be that the OP created a column named 'sample.  In that case, we `reorder` the 'Name' based on the `desc`ending order of 'Abundance'

```
df$sample <- "BC04"
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = sample,  y = Abundance, 
  fill = reorder(Name, desc(Abundance)))) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+ 
       guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Name"))
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option is to convert the 'Name' to `factor` with `levels` mentioned as the `unique` elements of 'Name' (as the data is already arranged in descending order of 'Abundance')

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample, y = Abundance, fill = Name)) +
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, reordering Name based on the already ordered Abundance was the best solution for me.